# Pipe or Service in Angular?

Tags: angular

I need to provide simple array of data with years.
What will be right to create: pipe or typically service class?

Iameging, that it is pipe. Then can I iterate this pipe in ngFor like this:

```
ngFor="item of pipe()"?
```

Comment: pipe isn't meant for types like that. Pipes are to transform outputvalue of existing array-elements. like that: ngFor="let item of array | uppercase"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an array in this case, neither **`pipe`** nor a **`service`**.

You can create an array by calling a function with the name pipe() though, that would return an array with your specified data.

Comment: So, I can use or `pipe` or `service` not difference? Can I call pipe name in ngFor?

Comment: i meant you should not

Comment: I got you, but I don't want to create the same array in each component, therefore. What then?

Comment: @OPV, You can move array to the file (e.g. `constants.ts`) and then import it in each component

Comment: @OPV did the answer help?

Comment: Yes, up me too please

Comment: I imported this in component, how to get access to this in template? `import {Years} from "./_services/Years";`